# sqlite3 - Column constraint not working

Tags: sqlite

Why is my last insert into the `Printer` table not returning an error? I thought (hoped) it would be rejected due to referential integrity.

### Code

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
Client (
    hostName    TEXT PRIMARY KEY,
    MACAddress  TEXT NOT NULL,
    deviceType  TEXT NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS
Printer (
    hostName    TEXT NOT NULL REFERENCES Client(hostName),
    outputType  TEXT NOT NULL,
    printerName TEXT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (hostname, outputType),
    FOREIGN KEY (hostName) REFERENCES Client(hostName)
      ON DELETE CASCADE
      ON UPDATE CASCADE
);

insert into Client (hostName, MACAddress, deviceType)
values ('billlaptop.private.ycc', 'bc:ea:c5:13:b3:09','Client');

insert into Printer (hostName, outputType, printerName)
values ('billlaptop.private.ycc', 'Receipt', 'Thermal');

insert into Printer (hostName, outputType, printerName)
values ('xxxx.private.ycc', 'Receipt', 'Thermal');

select * from Printer;
```

### Output

```
+--------------------------------------------------+
| hostName                outputType   printerName |
+--------------------------------------------------+
| billlaptop.private.ycc  Receipt      Thermal     |
| xxxx.private.ycc        Receipt      Thermal     |
+--------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Foreign key constraints are disabled by default per [documenation](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html#fk_enable). Use the `PRAGMA foreign_keys` command to enable:

```
sqlite> PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
```

[Fiddle with expected error.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/3980c/1)

Comment: Just finished two books on sqlite and neither of them mentioned it.

Answer (score 1):

Per the [SQLite3 pragma page](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_foreign_key_check), as of SQLite version 3.6.19, the default setting for foreign key enforcement is OFF.

You must issue a statement

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
```

to enable checking.